# How to get the birthday and email of the App downloader

Tags: google-play, google-plus, android

I'm developing an android application and needs to get the birthday and the email address of the person (in order to do some promotions) who is downloading the app from Google Play.

Is there a way to get it programatically?

Comment: u can propmt him/her for email and bdate

Comment: Without his/her knowledge isn't there a way to get them?

Comment: Get accounts from device, get Gmail Account and fire query for birthday in Google+ profile. You have to work with Google+ Android integration.

Comment: Don't get this data without the users consent/knowledge. It's shady and illegal in some countries.